# Will Ubuntu work fine on my Asus EEE netbook?

Tags: asus, ubuntu-netbook

I've got a Asus Eee PC 1015BX-WHI135S:

- AMD C-50; Dual Core; 1000 MHz
- 320 GB; SATA; 5400 rpm
- LCD-LED; 1024 x 600; 10,1 inches

Will the default Ubuntu 12.10 distro work fine on this machine? Or is it better to choose another distro (Lubuntu or Xubuntu)? Or maybe Unity 2D instead of 3D?

It runs Windows 7 Starter fine, but its slow with Windows 8...

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: RAM: 1GB (SO-DIMM DDR3)

Answer (score 1):

With your specifications I would try Lubuntu first.

Try it from a Live USB. If everything works you may proceed to install it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try Lubuntu this week... hopefully I'll enjoy it!

Comment: I like it (from Live USB)... maybe I'll try Xubuntu too...

Answer (score 1):

I have a eeePC 900A which has a lower spec CPU (1.6GHz Atom N270), and the standard install of Ubuntu 12.10 runs fine, although Firefox can be a bit slow to load javascript-heavy web pages.